# Mathematical difference between broad and narrow band Spectral estimation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, soft-question

Is there different mathematical formulation behind spectral estimation of narrow band and wide band? By spectral estimation I mean estimating the frequencies in a given signal. Fourier transform is fundamental, but there are other methods like subspace methods. Now consider a signal X which we know that is made up of narrow-band signals and signal Y which we know is made up of broad-band signals. By narrow-band I mean bandwidth is very small like a single sinusoidal. My question is what is the fundamental difference in spectral estimation between signal X and Y?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1511871/mathematical-difference-between-broad-and-narrow-band-spectral-estimation

Comment: Maybe this question is better suited to ask at http://dsp.stackexchange.com/